# Organic synthesis problems

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am an A-level student going into university and I am looking for a source of organic synthesis problems and answers that is freely available on the internet. The difficulty level I am looking for is something like first year undergraduate level. Any links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe there is some site where you can practice synthesizing a compound (theoretically of course) by selecting reactants and starting materials. Very nice idea, but unfortunately I cannot find it anymore... anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for the latest IChO tests and preparatory problems. You can find quite a few interesting problems.

Here are some tests:
http://www.iuventa.sk/files/documents/5_icho/past%20competition%20tasks/volume3-icho41-45.pdf

http://icho2013.chem.msu.ru/materials/Preparatory_problems_IChO_2013.pdf (problems 18-21)

http://icho2014.hus.edu.vn/Preparatory-Problems/0001/01/Preparatory-Problems-224.html (problems 18-26)

Answer (score 2):

Janice G. Smith's textbook "Organic Chemistry", while unfortunately expensive, has a good interactive workbook online which is useful even without the companion text.

You can find it [here](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0072397462/student_view0/index.html).

Comment: That website is not working for me. Does it work for anyone else?

Comment: @yolo123 Select the chapter, then open the corresponding multiple choice quiz.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing textbook problems e.g. those of David Klein and Clayden. In addition, it might be useful to refer to MIT open courseware's organic problems. I have included their links:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-12-organic-chemistry-i-spring-2003/
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-12-organic-chemistry-i-spring-2005/

These problems might be old, but I still found them useful... As for which year to do, I don't think it matters too much